# Javascript function to highlight Woocommerce-elements. Problems using querySelector()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am not an expert at neither PHP, nor frontend-Javascript, nor Wordpress. But I got asked to look at someones onlineshop. I am supposed to highlight the according subcategory, when looking at a product, inside a subcategory-widget. The problem here: one product may of course have a few subcategories, matching the ones inside the widget. So I got asked to just highlight the one, that is mentioned in the breadcrumbs. So I know that it's not very much of a pretty way to locate HTML-elements by their innerHTML, but I couldn't really figure out a better way. In the end of the day it doesn't work anyway.

Here you can find an example product of the shop.

So far my approach was adding this to the functions.php of our child-theme:

```
function highlight_subcat()
{
    if (is_product()) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                var subcategories = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=menu-item-] a");
                var breadcrumbString = document.querySelector("#main > div:nth-child(1) > nav > a:nth-child(3)").innerHTML;

                subcategories.forEach(function (subcat) {
                    if (subcat.innerHTML.localeCompare(breadcrumbString))
                        subcat.css("color", "white");
                });

            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'highlight_subcat');
```

Even though I used `css()` pretty much the same way earlier and it worked fine, I am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: subcat.css is not a function

My guess is that it's wrong usage of all that jquery-document-querySelector stuff. I'd be very grateful for some advise how to make this work. Or maybe there is a better approach for Wordpress in general?! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `subcat` is actually a `HTMLElement`, since it is obtained from the `NodeList` returned by the native `document.querySelectorAll()` method. It is not a jQuery object, so you can't use jQuery methods on it.

The simplest way is to actually set the CSSStyle natively, i.e.:

```
subcat.style.color = 'white';
```

...or convert it to a jQuery object to access jQuery's `.css()` method:

```
$(subcat).css('color', 'white');
```

Comment: Solved it. Helped me alot to understand a few things too. Thank you!